# Initialization of fields of a base class

Tags: python-3.x

I have two classes. In this example they are `Duck` and `Goose`. They have much in common, but some differences too. Naturally I create common parent class that holds all common methods. In this case it's a `Bird`.

They also have different `__init__` methods, which both initialize `self.sound` in different ways.

Methods of `Bird` class use `self.phrase` field, and i know for sure that all child classes have that field. But it makes no sense to create `__init__` method for `Bird`, as it is an abstract class, and it will be overwritten by both classes anyway. So my IDE highlights `self.sound` in `Bird` methods as an error, because it's not defined. And such usage also feels strange for me too.

Is there a more clean and natural way to use `self.sound` in common methods without creating a 'fake' `__init__` in `Bird` class?

```
class Bird(ABC):
    def speak(self):
        print(self.sound)

    def fly(self):
        print('flop-flop-flop')


class Duck(Bird):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.sound = phrase

    def dive(self):
        print("pfpfm...")


class Goose(Bird):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.sound = phrase + '!!!'

    def run(self):
        print('stomp stomp stomp')
```

I know one way around is to declare `self.sound` as a property

```
class Bird(ABC):
    @property
    def self.sound(self):
        pass

    def speak(self):
        print(self.sound)

    def fly(self):
        print('flop-flop-flop')


class Duck(Bird):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self._sound = phrase

    @property
    def sound(self):
        return self._sound

    def dive(self):
        print("pfpfm...")


class Goose(Bird):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self._sound = phrase + '!!!'

    @property
    def sound(self):
        return self._sound

    def run(self):
        print('stomp stomp stomp')
```

but in 3 classes total it takes so much space for a single field. And there can be many fields like this. And now classes `Duck` and `Goose` repeat themselves again. Are there other ways how i can achieve the same?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with creating a constructor of the form `def __init__(self, sound): self.sound = sound` for the `Bird` class, and then _extending_ it for `Goose`: `def __init__(self, phrase): super().__init__(phrase + '!!!')`?

Comment: @kolokkol yeah, thanks. This could be an alternative. I now was going to say that this wouldn't work in my real-world problem, but i looked closer in my code, and i indeed can separate some fields into a common `__init__`, and in this case adding there some placeholders for completely differently initialized fields doesn't look as weird anymore.